# Subtring string='aaaa/bbb/ccc/dd' from last slash to get 'dd'

Tags: angular, string, replace, substring

I need to get the last part of my string.

For example, my string is  :
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy.pdf`

What can I do to get only the last part behind the last slash? `dummy.pdf`

But without using a static substring, because my string can be for example :  `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/SOMEFOLDER/BLABLA/dummy.pdf`

But I want the last part of this, `dummy.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a regex replacement:

```js
var input = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy.pdf";
var output = input.replace(/^.*\//, "");
console.log(output);
```

Another option, using string split:

```js
var input = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy.pdf";
var parts = input.split("/");
var output = parts[parts.length-1];
console.log(output);
```